# Do I have to have an IDFA when I use AdMob?

Tags: ios, admob, idfa

I have successfully added interstitial ads to my app and I'm about to submit it for review.

Do I have to use IDFA to pass?

Comment: Can you elaborate? In an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to do much on your end after implementing AdMob ads as AdMob is already taking care of it i.e. IDFA is already utilized in AdMob. Just Apple will ask you some questions with checkboxes to answers while submitting the app finally. I don't remember exactly what these questions are, being a few months submitting an app. Found the questions in the below link,[Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)? - AdMob 6.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124663/does-this-app-use-the-advertising-identifier-idfa-admob-6-8-0)

Comment: So do you check yes if you use AdMob?