# How do I check where my app is using IDFA

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, mopub, idfa

While submitting my app to the App Store, I got this message: "Your app is using the Advertising Identifier (IDFA). You must either provide details about the IDFA usage or remove it from the app and submit your binary again."

I am no longer displaying ads so I said that I was not using the IDFA when I was asked. I also tried submitting the app by saying that I was using the IDFA to display targeted ads.

When I WAS displaying ads, I was using MoPub and Facebook Audience Network. Is there a way to see where I was using the IDFA?

Comment: For people using Google AdMob  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23358377/1356559

Comment: I got this error on Cordova app. This solution works for me. https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/issues/218#issuecomment-248194925

Answer (score 144, accepted):

In order to check Advertising Identifier, you need to follow the following steps:

1. Open the terminal window. Run the following command:

   ```
   cd (drag and drop your project folder here) Your_Project_Path
   ```

   Now, the current working directory will be your project folder.
2. Find all the SDK that uses "Advertising Identifier" using following commands:

   ```
   find . | grep -v .svn | grep "\.a" | grep -v "\.app" | xargs grep advertisingIdentifier
   ```

   or

   ```
   find . -type f | grep "\.a" | grep -v "\.app" | xargs grep advertisingIdentifier
   ```

   and / or

   ```
   grep -lr "advertisingIdentifier" * | grep -v .svn | grep -v .md
   ```
3. After getting the list of frameworks, search for the frameworks that MATCHES the query. Remove/ Upgrade those frameworks as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks buddy u saved my time

Comment: Perfect solution !

Comment: i used this link too 
http://masteringionic.com/blog/2017-03-20-resolving-the-itunes-connect-idfa-warning-when-using-the-cordova-google-analytics-plugin/

Comment: I am getting Command not found, for all the commands. Now my app is using idfa or not.

Comment: grep -lr "advertisingIdentifier" * | grep -v .svn | grep -v .md        - this command works for me and it gave the results that which pod libraries using idfa.

Comment: @R.Mohan that command is already listed in my answer. Please upvote if it helped. Thanks :)

Comment: Upvoted, but i don't know why it did not worked while i am copy pasting from your answer.

Comment: @R.Mohan, don't copy the first $

Comment: @R.Mohan what can we do after getting list of library

Comment: @Jaydip, i did not remember what I did two years before, after checking the answer and my comment too :p

Comment: @Jaydip you either remove them or update them as mentioned in step 3.

Comment: iOS 6.0 onwards you need to find **identifierForVendor** not 'advertisingIdentifier'