# Advertising Identifier (IDFA) issue when submitting the app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, idfa

When I try to submit my iOS app to Appstore I got this error message in itunesConnect.

```
Your app is using the Advertising Identifier (IDFA). You must either provide details about the IDFA usage or remove it from the app and submit your binary again.
```

So I tried to find those in this way .in my terminal.

```
grep -lr "advertisingIdentifier" * | grep -v .svn | grep -v .md
```

The output is

```
MyProj/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK
MyProj/amigo/FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/FacebookSDK
MyProj/FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/Current/FacebookSDK
MyProj/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork
MyProj/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/Versions/A/FBAudienceNetwork
MyProj/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/Versions/Current/FBAudienceNetwork
```

I have integrated G+.FB and twitter logging.So now what should I do to resolve this issue? I can't remove these coz I need this within my app. Please help me.Thanks

Comment: are you using IAdframework in your project

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779092/how-do-i-check-where-my-app-is-using-idfa

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik No I don't use it

Comment: yeas I checked this link. According to that command Im getting this output. After I found those what should I do?

Comment: please remove the FBAudienceNetwork.framework its use for Advertising.check link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/native-ads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook Audience Network SDK uses the Advertising Identifier in order to serve ads in the app. According to [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW1) and [Facebook Audience Network documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#faq_464771113731150), when you click on "Submit for Review", you need to check the purposes related to the use of IDFA in your app:

> This app uses the Advertising Identifier to (select all that apply)?
>
> - Serve advertisements within the app
> - Attribute this app installation to a previously served advertisement
> - Attribute an action taken within this app to a previously served advertisement.
>
> If you will be using the
>   Audience Network framework, you must select the first option. If you
>   are using our core framework to track install attribution and app
>   events, please select the second and third options. If you are using
>   both, select all three.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your suggestion. I removed FBAudience library from Link Binary with Libraries, but then im getting an error like this. Build fail. Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSpamSignal.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)