# How do I know if my app is using IDFA

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I did not use any IDFA however when I have sent it in for review apple says that my app uses IDFA and rejected my app. I have tried to follow [How do I check where my app is using IDFA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31779425/4952714) instruction but I did not receive any output is this normal? or did I do anything wrongly?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any advertising libraries in your app - like Google's AdMob?

Comment: @Craig I didn't. The only libraries I have use in my app is OpenCV

Comment: That's odd then… AFAIK OpenCV doesn't use it… you may have to open a question in the resolution centre

Comment: While you are uploading the app to app store and try to submit for approval the app store itself will check the binary and will say if it has any code related to advertising like ADMob or something like that.