# Is there any way to generate an unique ID for device without using IDFA?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store

I have to generate an unique ID for each device. Right now, I take device's unique ID with this way:

```
let uniqueStr = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
```

But in **App Store Submission**, this error come up:

> Your app is using the Advertising Identifier (IDFA). You must either
>   provide details about the IDFA usage or remove it from the app and
>   submit your binary again.

My app has nothing to do with advertisement at all. Is there any way to get unique ID without getting this IDFA error?

Comment: Have you added `AdSupport.framework` in your app?

Comment: If the user uninstalls and then reinstalls the app to his device do you want the ID to be the same?

Comment: Are you sure `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString` is causing the problem? DO you get any message from apple for it? By the way, you can check IDFA to yes also, with `Serve advertisements within the app` option uncheck. It means you have IDFA but not displaying ad, IDFA may be enabled due to the some 3rd party library you have used? for more detail https://segment.com/docs/sources/mobile/ios/quickstart/#step-5-submitting-to-the-app-store

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal No, I didn't add AdSupport framework.

Comment: @Aris Yes, it must be the same.

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal No, I am not sure but I added this after previous submission. I also added 3rd party framework which can use IDFA. I'll ask to them if this isn't the cause.

Comment: Possibly Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779092/how-do-i-check-where-my-app-is-using-idfa

Comment: Are you using any adNetwork campaign in your app. Usually this adNetwork use Advertising Identifier (IDFA) and while submitting your app you need to mark it as a YES

Comment: @Shruti No, I am not using adNetwork campaign. I guess 3rd party framework causes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that apple throws this error when **Advertising Identifier (IDFA)** is being used not **identifierForVendor**.

It might be possible that some 3rd party library is using it. You can check for the actual reason for what or which framework using the IDFA from below stackoverflow answer:

[How do I check where my app is using IDFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779092/how-do-i-check-where-my-app-is-using-idfa)

Then,

1. Either update your library accordingly or
2. You can select using IDFA option while submitting the app.

Comment: If you believe that the question is a duplicate, flag it as such. Adding an answer that simply references the duplicate isn't necessary.