# IDFA not used, do we need to show App Tracking Transparency popup?

Tags: ios, tvos, appstore-approval, apple-developer, idfa

Seeking expert advice

I am working on an OTT platform for a client that has iOS and tvOS apps;

I am a bit confused about whether we should show the App Tracking Transparency pop up for this app if we are not using IDFA.

We are using the following analytical tools in our apps.

- Firebase Analytics and Crashlytics
- Mixpannel
- Youbora

I made sure that any SDK is not using IDFA using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779092/how-do-i-check-where-my-app-is-using-idfa) method.

Additionally, we send identifiers to large content delivery networks like Akamai to give the users a personalized experience.

When we submitted the tvOS app for the first time, it was rejected for not showing the ATT popup. (Existing iOS app is already showing it)

These are the App Privacy information added by the iOS team in App Store.
[image]

**I seriously doubt that we don't need to show this popup since we are not using IDFA identifier. Is that correct?** We can use these analytical tools and all even if the user denying the tracking option. So if we show this popup unnecessarily, it will create a negative impact on the user experience.

Comment: If they refused it, there is a reason. I think that more than asking here you should ask Apple (when they refuse you an app you can send them messages to better understand the problem and try to solve it). However, the ATT request is necessary to obtain the IDFA, so even if you requested it without ATT, you would only get a lot of zeros. If you say you don't use it, then you need to ask them the reason for the refusal and how best to behave

Comment: Thanks for your comment @FreeLearning. Since my client manages the apple account, I cannot ask Apple directly about this. I understood ATT request is necessary to obtain the IDFA, but in this project, we are not using IDFA. Even though apple asked for this because of the tracking info we provided in Appstore connect. We are not sure which one of these triggered the flag.

Comment: As you said it is strange. However instead of contacting them from the refusal of the app you can also try to contact from here (https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store-connect/), it is general support, but maybe you can ask for clarification. 
Otherwise if you can't talk to them but you can manage the metadata of the submission, you can try to write in the "Notes" section, what you said here, where you explain that you don't use IDFA, and resubmit.