# Is it neccessary to check something before using advertisingIdentifier?

Tags: ios, iphone

I user iOS advertisingIdentifier like below code in my iOS app:

```
 NSString *adId = [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
```

without any check to anything. and send it to the server. Server gives some point to the users that are installing the app for first time. I user this code to detect first installation.

Right now I want to publish the app to the store. The store show below text to me:

> I, husein behboodi rad, confirm that this app, and any third party
>   that interfaces with this app, uses the Advertising Identifier checks
>   and honors a user's Limit Ad Tracking setting in iOS and, when it is
>   enabled by a user, this app does not use Advertising Identifier, and
>   any information obtained through the use of the Advertising
>   Identifier, in any way other than for "Limited Advertising Purposes"
>   as defined in the iOS Developer Program License Agreement.

I do not undestand their meaning. Does I need do check something about Limit Ad Tracking before using above code?

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124663/does-this-app-use-the-advertising-identifier-idfa-admob-6-8-0

Comment: so I do not need to check any thing to be enabled or not for using this identifier?

Comment: follow the link I added to my comment. Check whatever applies to you, agree to the agreement. See the second answer to know how to check if your 3rd party apps and your app uses IDFA. If they pass the test, your app will be approved.

Comment: I am sure that only I myself user the id. but I want to be sure that I do not need to check any if statment for checking any states before using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using the advertising identifier for ad tracking you should check the `advertisingTrackingEnabled` property of `ASIdentifierManager`.  The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ASIdentifierManager/advertisingTrackingEnabled) for this property states:

> Check the value of this property before performing any advertising
>   tracking. If the value is NO, use the advertising identifier only for
>   the following purposes: frequency capping, attribution, conversion
>   events, estimating the number of unique users, advertising fraud
>   detection, and debugging.

From your question it seems that your use of the identifier would be covered by "estimating the number of unique users", in which case you don't need to check `advertisingTrackingEnabled`.

Be aware though, that the user can reset the advertising identifier at any time from iOS settings.