# Apple Developer Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?

Tags: ios, admob, app-store-connect

I am uploading my game to the app store does this question of saying yes to my app containing the IDFA matter if I am using google ad mob?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)? - AdMob 6.8.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124663/does-this-app-use-the-advertising-identifier-idfa-admob-6-8-0)

Answer (score 1):

I use Appodeal which use Ad Mob and I have to check :
- Save Advertisements within the App
- Atribute this App installation ....
- Limit Ad tracking setting in IOS

Answer (score 1):

Few very simple steps you need to follow:

- If you have no Ads in your Application than simply click no & submit
- If your App contains Ads than click on Yes & it will show you few more check boxes
- If you are just showing ads in the Application no other process is there than simply choose first option "Serve advertisement within App"

Hope it will help you.