# Does AdMob uses IDFA?

Tags: swift, admob

I am trying to submit an update of my app but it shows me some questions and I don't know what to check. I am using AdMob in my app just showing banners. I saw this post [Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)? - AdMob 6.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124663/does-this-app-use-the-advertising-identifier-idfa-admob-6-8-0) and they say that AdMob does use IDFA, but
**my question is:** Do I need to add some extra code to my project? and 
What should I check?

Answer (score 1):

im always submitting the apps with chcked box, it's better to do even if you know it has IDFA.. so your on the good side.. otherwize you need to upload new build if its going to be rejected!

Comment: Which box you're talking about? Should I say "yes" it uses IDFA?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add code to your project.
You should check the "serve ads within the app"