# Does this app use Advertising Identifier Checkboxes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes-app

I have an app which i need to upload to the store. I use admob for advertisements. I know that admob uses IDFA. when trying to upload i see three checkboxes,

> - Serve Advertisements within the app
> - Attribute this app installation to a previously served advertisement
> - Attribute an action taken within this app to previously served advertisement

What exactly does these lines means? The first option, i think it simply means that we are using the advertisement inside the app. But i am not clear about the other two options. When should i check the other two options? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124663/does-this-app-use-the-advertising-identifier-idfa-admob-6-8-0) post, but the answers didn't explain about the last two options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some ads are intended to get users to install or deep link to installed apps.  These checkboxes indicate if the advertising identifier is used to track these kinds of behaviors.

So what those two items are asking is:

*1. Are you going to use the IDFA to track users that are installing your app from ads?*

*2. Are you going to use the IDFA to track users that follow deep links into your app from ads?*

IDFA is used this way so that the marketers can measure the effectiveness of the ads.  [Here's an article](https://help.tune.com/marketing-console/how-to-submit-your-app-when-it-uses-idfa/) that talks about it in relation to a particular vendor's SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If I'm not doing anything but showing ads? Could google be doing those things if I'm just displaying ads from AdMob? That link is a 404

Comment: The first condition is _Serve Advertisements within the app_, so yes, if the app is displaying ads, then it is using the IDFA.