# Can I use AdMob in android apps published on AppGallery of Huawei?

Tags: android, google-play, admob, ads, huawei-mobile-services

Can I use AdMob ads in my Android apps on AppGallery of Huawei (Huawei Store)?

If not, what ad networks can I use?

Answer (score 6):

Huawei has no restrictions on third-party ad platforms. You may use AdMob but it cannot generate revenue from devices where Google Mobile Services (GMS) is not installed.

You can use [Huawei Ads kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-adskit) as an alternative.

Comment: how true is this ?

Comment: @neobie Yes, it is true.

Comment: You may use AdMob. It is recommended to use [HMS Ads kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-adskit) as an alternative.

Comment: what is your source for saying that it cannot generate revenue from devices where Google Mobile Services (GMS) is not installed? I am interested in setting up ads for non-china users

Comment: @josue.0 It is because to display ad content does not require gms, but the settlement of Admob requires gms. :)

Comment: Thanks, btw the last version of admob makes Google Play Services mandatory because they now require [this library](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) which is in [the list of GMS dependent libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services#google_play_services_required_or_recommended)

Answer (score 0):

The regulation for [In-App Advertisement](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/devservice/doc/30202#id5) seems compatible to AdMob, with something should be noticed.

> 5.3 In-app advertisements must be suitable for their target groups.

Google is banned in China, and *may* so does AdMob, which may result in a "not-suitable".

> 5.6 Your app must not link advertisement identifiers with user identities or permanent device identifiers, such as SSAIDs, MAC addresses, and IMEIs, without users' explicit permission.

Due to [Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)? - AdMob 6.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124663), I am afraid this can cause a rejection.

Comment: may - is not an answer, you should answer if you are not sure if AdMob is banned or note

Comment: pure speculation. It says without user permission...

Answer (score -1):

You can use AdMob on AppGallery apps, However, you won't get anything from Chinese users of our app, AdMob is blocked in China.

Comment: Does it mean, that I need to use Ads Kit from App Gallery console?

Comment: The question was about Huawei app store(Huawei app gallery) which is available worldwide , not about China