# Advertising Identifier (IDFA)? - Admob

Tags: ios, admob, app-store, app-store-connect

I developed a buildbox game. In the game, I am using admob. I uploaded binary to App Store. This is the last question.

[image]

Which checkbox should be checked all of them or only third one?

I am using only Admob, no other library.

Comment: Related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23124663/3780985

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are serving an adds in your app you shoud check the first checkbox. Second and third one are optionals. The fourth one is required so you must check it.

Comment: I checked first and fourth one. My app is approved.